# First steps using classes in C#, using a method internal variable into another method

Tags: c#, class, oop, console-application

I have been trying to write my 1st program using classes, Im new to C# in Visual Studio and its also worth mentioning its been a while (2 yeas) since i used OOP Im looking for a way to get this up and running by practice, its a simple program to calculate the area, perimeter and volume of a poligon.

I havent been able to modify the propertiers of the class even though i get no error, and i dont get any values into my class properties, also, i was intending to pull out the methods from the class to my main, and use them to do the math, by using

**1.- How do can the variable P be saved into the same class properties, for further use into another method?**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        VolumenPrisma Herramienta = new VolumenPrisma();
        VolumenPrisma.Registro();
    }
}    

namespace Poligono
{
    public class VolumenPrisma
    {
        public static int Apotema, TamLado, NumLados, Altura, lado;

        public static double cPerimetro (int NumLados, int lado){
            double P;
            P=(NumLados*lado);
            return P;    
        }

        public static void Registro(){
            Console.WriteLine("Indique No. de lados: ");
            VolumenPrisma.NumLados = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Indique tamanio de lado: ");
            VolumenPrisma.lado = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());    
            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("Perimetro = {0} ",VolumenPrisma.cPerimetro(NumLados,lado));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you make it smaller, more focused on your problem? It contains multiple `ReadLine()`s, and a lot of unrelated code.

Comment: I tried this on my machine and it does write the property values. Why do you think it is not?

Comment: because when i call the function perimeter it does not actually do the math and the result of cPerimetro comes out as 0

Comment: That's because `lado` is never set, so perhaps it stays initialized at 0?  Needless to say, anything multiplied by 0 is zero.

Comment: sorry i just modified the code in order for it to make sense, and reduce its size, as you can sse i write 2 properties, and then call the fuction cPerimeter that ends up coimg out as 0 even when both NumLado and Ldo are supposed to have values

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work for you. The code works fine for me. Is there something else you are missing?

Comment: looks like i had a single typo "Lado" instead of "lado", sorry about that the code its calculating the perimeter as intended, Im just a bit tired, still i edited the question in order to keep editing the code, the question just ends up asking how can i use the variable P as a variable into another method in the same class i found out by editing the code in the question

Comment: you can put the smaller part of the problem here https://dotnetfiddle.net/ so the community can help you better

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is more a modular solution than OOP (object oriented programming).
Object oriented means to create an object, an instance of a given class to fulfill some specific task:

```
VolumenPrisma herramienta = new VolumenPrisma();
```

Now it is the duty of this instance to perform the work:

```
herramienta.Registro();
var perimeter = herramienta.Perimetro();
```

Because the `Perimetro()` method gives you back a simple calculation of the two values you read in `Registro()`, it is perfect to design it as property:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        VolumenPrisma herramienta = new VolumenPrisma();
        herramienta.Registro();

    }
}    

namespace Poligono
{
    public class VolumenPrisma
    {
        private int numLados;
        private int lado;

        public double Perimetro
        {               
            get { return numLados * lado; }
        }

        public void Registro()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Indique No. de lados: ");
            numLados = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Indique tamanio de lado: ");
            lado = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");

            Console.WriteLine("Perimetro = {0} ", Perimetro);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare P as a variable along with all the other variables you are preserving, instead of as a local.

```
public static int Apotema, TamLado, NumLados, Altura, lado, P;

public static double cPerimetro (int NumLados, int lado){
    P=(NumLados*lado);
    return P;    
}
```

Although if you're going to do this, I'd suggest a more descriptive variable name than P.

If you only will be using P from within  the class, you can declare it private:

```
public static int Apotema, TamLado, NumLados, Altura, lado;
private static int P;

public static double cPerimetro (int NumLados, int lado){
    P=(NumLados*lado);
    return P;    
}
```